# how to use PHP 5.2 in 2017 ? | Zend Guard Loader version issue with php

Tags: php, linux, centos, zend-guard

I have codebase from year 2009, the company which developed the solution encoded it with zend guard encoder 5.5 with PHP version 5.2.

Currently , I am running it on VPS with Windows Server with installing php 5.2 and zend guard extension without any hassle.

Now , I want to shift it to Any Linux Server as Maintaining windows server is getting expensive ( +19% GST in india ).

Issue is I am not able to install PHP 5.2 literally on any modern VPS.
as PHP 5.2 EOL half decade ago , no Linux Distro supporting it now.
I tried all the ways adding numorous repos, compiling from source , nothing seems to work.

According to Zend Forum : https://zend18.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217058968
It needs to be php 5.2 only.

Even Digitalocean , Godaddy VPS not supporting absolute Linux Distros.
and i dont think Dedicated server is Valid Option.

Please let me know what is the way to do it.

Comment: Short answer: **don't**. If you can't get a copy of the software which will run on a modern version of PHP, stop using it and find an alternative.

Comment: simply can't.
it was developed way back half decade ago but still works fine  , cant contact previous developer as that company doesnt exist anymore.